# FPDI PDF Parser eats "Print" Button within document

Tags: parsing, pdf, fpdi

i use FPDI-PDF for parsing a PDF Document. I have a "print this form" button within my document.
It works when i open the file in PDF Reader.

When i run this file through FPDI-PDF the "print this form" button is gone.
The file was saved as Adobe PDF Version 1.4 (Reader 5.0) so FPDI-PDF can read it.

Any idea how i can verify where the button remained or why it is not Displayed in the FPDI-PDF Output PDF File?

Best Regards
Stonegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FPDI is not able to import dynamic content like form fields/buttons as you may also read in its [FAQ](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-206).

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. Do you know of any alternative tool that is able to add dynamic Content into a PDF (for invoicing for example.) that does not remove the print button ?

Comment: If you want to add content to the existing document you may check out the [SetaPDF-Stamper](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-stamper/details/) component. It will work on the exiting document and will not create a new one as you do with FPDI.